# MySQL, Store Procedure, How get result from both queries, Updated solve

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count, rowset

My Procedure: (It's a scheme)

```
  delimiter //
  CREATE PROCEDURE get_random_data()
  BEGIN
  Declare Count_a INT;
      SELECT Floor(Count(`id_x`) * Rand()) INTO Count_a From `x_data`  Where `ok_w` = 1 And `active` = 2 And `time` >= Unix_timestamp();

   # Now We select Some Rows
   SELECT `id_x` From `x_data` Where `spec` = 1 Limit Count_a,3;

   # And if Count of this select is small than < 3

   IF(row_count() < 3) then
      SELECT `id_anonsu` From `x_data` Where `spec` = 0 Limit Count_a,2;
   END IF ;


  END//
  delimiter ;
```

// Target

How to get the results From BOTH queries?
// One from query before if statement

// Second from query in statement, if first query count is smaller than 3

Comment: I don't really understand your question...you want to get the result from BOTH queries? what do you mean with getting the result and rowset?

Comment: Yes, I want get result from Both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

The original code:

```
   IF(row_count() < 3) then
       SELECT `id_anonsu` From `x_data` Where `spec` = 0 Limit Count_a,2;
   END IF ;
```

Was replaced for:

```
IF(FOUND_ROWS() < 3) THEN SELECT `id_anonsu` From `x_data` Where `spec` = 0 Limit Count_a,2;
END IF ;
```

---

Better Version:

Work Good with query (Who use LIMIT)
And we need know number of returned rows by (Query)in  Store Procedure

Version with show count

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
    Delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE test(OUT w INT)
    BEGIN
    Declare Counter_a INT DEFAULT 0;


        Set @id_counter = 0;

        SELECT Floor(Count(`id_x`) * Rand()) INTO Counter_a From `x_data`  Where `ok_w` = 1 And `active` = 2 And `time` >= Unix_timestamp();

        SELECT @id_counter := @id_counter + 1, `id_x` From `x_data` Where `spec` = 1 Limit Counter_a,3;


        IF @id_counter < 3 THEN 
            Set Counter_a = Counter_a + 1;
            SELECT `id_x` From `x_data` Limit Counter_a,2;


        END IF;

        Set w = @id_counter;


    END //
    Delimiter ;
```

Output like this:

```
  mysql> Call test(@z); Select @z;
  +--------------------------------+-----------+
  | @id_counter := @id_counter + 1 |   id_x    |
  +--------------------------------+-----------+
  |                              1 |         7 |
  |                              2 |         8 |
  +--------------------------------+-----------+
  2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  +-----------+
  |   id_x    |
  +-----------+
  |         8 |
  +-----------+
  1 row in set (0.01 sec)

  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

  +------+
  | @z   |
  +------+
  |    2 |
  +------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

---

Version with hidden count

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
    Delimiter //
    CREATE PROCEDURE test(OUT w INT)
    BEGIN
    Declare Counter_a INT DEFAULT 0;


        Set @id_counter = 0;

        SELECT Floor(Count(`id_x`) * Rand()) INTO Counter_a From `x_data`  Where `ok_w` = 1 And `active` = 2 And `time` >= Unix_timestamp();

        SELECT `id_x` From `x_data` Where @id_counter := @id_counter + 1 And `spec` = 1 Limit Counter_a,3;


        IF @id_counter < 3 THEN 
            Set Counter_a = Counter_a + 1;
            SELECT `id_x` From `x_data` Limit Counter_a,2;


        END IF;

        Set w = @id_counter;


    END //
    Delimiter ;
```

Output like this:

```
  mysql> Call test(@z); Select @z;
  +-----------+
  |   id_x    |
  +-----------+
  |         7 |
  |         8 |
  +-----------+
  2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  +-----------+
  |   id_x    |
  +-----------+
  |         8 |
  +-----------+
  1 row in set (0.01 sec)

  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

  +------+
  | @z   |
  +------+
  |    2 |
  +------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

@TIP

```
 @id_counter := @id_counter + 1
```

It's Must be before all conditions in where.

For example:

```
[.....] Where @id_counter := @id_counter + 1 And `field_2` > 1 LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Will return always 1...

---

Correct Version

```
[.....] Where `field_2` > 1 And  [Other conditions] And @id_counter := @id_counter + 1  LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on client interface you use. JDBC for example has statement.getMoreResults()

It is funny that the  query contains delimeter // and // comments at the same time.

Comment: I use mysql command-line, but after execution (5x), i always got only one result..